# CakePHP login (not users table)

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, frameworks

How  can I use another table for login someone?
I've create a table called 'membre' for example. (field : id / password / name / id_post )

My view code :

```php
<h2>Se connecter</h2>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Portfolio'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', $options = array('label' => 'Login :')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', $options = array('label : ' => 'Mot de passe')); ?>


<?php echo $this->Form->end("Se connecter");

?>
```

My appController :

```php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Session', 'Cookie',
     'Auth' => array(
                    'authenticate' => array(
                                            'Form' => array(
                                                'scope' => array('Membre.valide' => 1)
                                                )
                                            )
                    )
     );

    function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Membre'
    )
);
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'membres', 'action' => 'login', 'membre' => false, 'admin' => false);
        if (!isset($this->request->params['prefix'])) {
            $this->Auth->allow();
        }



    }

}
```

And my MembresController

```php
 function login() {
            $membre_id = $this->Auth->membre('id'); /// test si deja connecter
            $passeError= false ;
            if ($membre_id) {
                        $this->redirect('/');
                        die('');
                    }

            if($this->request->is('post')) {  //verif si es info son envoyer

                if($this->Auth->login()){
                    $this->Membre->id= $this->Auth->user('id');

                    $this->Session->setFlash('Vous etes maintenant connecter');
                    $this->redirect('/');

                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Mauvais identifiant');

                }

            }



        }
```

Comment: Note that `$options = array('label : ' => ...)` is not valid CakePHP code. the labe would not have an effect. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have part of your Auth array mixed up. What you want is:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'all' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Membre',
            'scope' => array('Membre.valide' => 1)
        )
    )
)
```

(All other keys omitted for brevity)

By the way, it's really hard to read your code with it tabbed that far.

Edit:
You're also going to need to modify your view code a bit. Either change `$this->Form->create('Portfolio')` to `$this->Form->create('Membre')` or change the field names to `'Membre.name'` and `'Membre.password'`, or they'll be submitted under the wrong array.